Simulate location on real Apple Watch using Xcode
In Xcode I have several gpx files and I can perfectly simulate my location when using my iPhone. But when I run my counterpart AppleWatch App, the simulate location menu in Xcode is completely greyed out. I already checked that in my scheme settings, the "Allow Location Simulation" checkbox is checked. And even then I use a default location there, it will not use that location on the AppleWatch.
Am I the only one with that problem? Would be awesome to get some hints on how to solve that. Or am I missing something else?



Did you check your info.plist to see if it is enabled there?

I'm having this problem too (Xcode 15.4) which suggests its a current Xcode issue.
